# Split a file content or a string to an array of string of the SAME size

Tags: c, arrays, string

I need an advice about C programming. I need to split a file (or its content) to an array of char. I found all over the internet different solutions to either split a file to different smaller files or split a string to an array but using delimiters with strtok()

The thing is : I need to split it et store it into an array of char but each elements must have the same size (64 bits)

Do you guys have any idea how I can do it ( Using the standard C library ) ?
Any advices would be greatly appreciated.

TO be clearer : I managed to split a file into several smallers files of the same size example :

```
Zeddis@localhost $> ls -la
-rw-rw-r--. 1 Zeddis Zeddis     64 28 févr. 23:17 filepart_number_10
-rw-rw-r--. 1 Zeddis Zeddis     64 28 févr. 23:17 filepart_number_11
-rw-rw-r--. 1 Zeddis Zeddis     64 28 févr. 23:17 filepart_number_12
[...]
```

but I need to store the content into an array, not files and each element's size has to be 64.

lets say I have a 2mb .txt file, I need to store its content to an array where its element's size is 64 bits.

```
test.txt content : qwertyuiopasdfgh"

a[0] = "qwer"
a[1] = "tyui"
a[2] = "opas"
a[3] = "dfgh"

[...]
```

NB : I used char for the example but it could be int or anything, I just need each element to be the same size.
I hope you understood since English is not my native language.

Comment: _I need to .. store it into an array of char but each element must have the same size (64 bits)._ - What does this mean? `char`s are always 8 bits.

Comment: I meant that if I have let's say a test.txt file zith random content ( like a cat of /dev/urandom) I need to store its content into an array where each element have the same size.

Can I assume that a[)] = "aaaa" and a[1] = "q2#@" have the same size ? that maybe the thing that confuse me

Comment: What if length of the content is not multiple of 64? Note: Yes, "aaaa" and "q2#@" have the same size since they both have 5 chars and the size of char is fixed.

Comment: Do you mean 64 bits? Your example `a[0] = "qwer"` shows 32 bits (four 8-bit bytes) and your file example shows 64 **byte** files.

Comment: strings in C are `\0` delimited arrays of chars.   Files can have `\0` chars inside.  How can we cope with this before being able to give you an answer?  In your example, suppose your file contents are: `qwert\0yuiopasdfgh` what do we do with that `\0` character in between `t` and `y`?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example, perhaps it will be usefull:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    FILE * f;
    int64_t buffer;
    // check that file name is given and file is available
    if(argc == 2)
    {
        f = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
        if( f == NULL )
        {
            printf("File %s cannot be read!\n", argv[1]);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else
        {
            printf("File name needed!\n");
            return 1;
        }
    // reading from file to buffer in the loop
    while( !feof(f) )
    {
        if( 1 == fread(&buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, f) )
        {
            // do something with buffer (e.g. copy value to array)
            // ...
        }
    }
    // ...
    fclose(f);
}
```

**EDIT:**

For the case of `char[8]` (64 bits) array as a buffer:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    FILE * f;
    char charbuf[8];
    int cnt;
    // check that file name is given and file is available
    if(argc == 2)
    {
        f = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
        if( f == NULL )
        {
            printf("File %s cannot be read!\n", argv[1]);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else
        {
            printf("File name needed!\n");
            return 1;
        }
    // reading from file to buffer in the loop
    while( !feof(f) )
    {
        if( 8 == fread(charbuf, sizeof(char), 8, f) ) // only if 8 bytes was read
        {
            // do something with buffer
            // e.g. output all chars
            for(cnt = 0; cnt < 8; cnt++)
                putchar(charbuf[cnt]);
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }
    // ...
    fclose(f);
}
```